# Make gprbuild default to parallel builds?

Tags: ada

How do I make gprbuild default to doing parallel builds? It's not 1990 any more, and I have all these spare cores and don't want to have to keep adding `-j0` onto the command line.

From my understanding of the docs, this should work:

```
package Builder is
    for Default_Switches("Builder") use ("-j0");
end Builder;
```

...but it doesn't; it's just ignored. I've seen mentions on the interwebs that `Default_Switches("Ada")` should work, but all that does is pass the `--jobs` option to GNAT, which is of course wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t see anywhere in the sources of `gprbuild` where the number of jobs can be controlled except by `-j`.

However, the [documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html#package-Builder-in-aggregate-projects) suggests that you gan get the effect you want using an “aggregate project”. I wrapped one of my project files in an aggregate like so:

```
aggregate project Gnat_Util_Aggregate is
   for Project_Files use ("gnat_util.gpr");
   package Builder is
      for Switches (others) use ("-j0");
   end Builder;
end Gnat_Util_Aggregate;
```

The times for the plain project build  on this 13” Macbook Pro were

```
   70.17 real        66.33 user         2.85 sys
```

and for the aggregate project build

```
   35.46 real       119.05 user         4.80 sys
```

(I have no idea what the “user” values mean! but I checked the “real” values and they match my wristwatch.)

I’ve reported the error on the GPRBuild documentation link above (it says `for Switches (other)`, should be `others`) to AdaCore.

UPDATE: following David’s justified complaint, and on a hunch, I tried this `package Builder` trick in my plain project **and it worked**. I still don’t see where this happens in the sources.

For info, the undocumented switch `-dm` reports the maximum number of simultaneous compilations (in both `gnatmake` and `gprbuild`).

Comment: trashgod, thanks. Surprising then that it takes twice as much total CPU time to do the job using 4 cores as it does with just one. Communications/cache misses/waiting for disk, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks (even though using an aggregate project just to pass parameters is really ugly). Odd there isn't an internal option for this.

Comment: :blush: (though given the lack of documentation I don’t feel *too* bad). See the updated answer for Good News.

Comment: Yes --- that works nicely. Thanks very much! Now, if only `-p` worked there as well...